# Javascript to enable Activex control

Tags: javascript, java, windows, internet-explorer-11, activexobject

I want to use ActiveXObject to get some data from the client side.I am using IE 11. By default ActiveXObject is disabled in browser.So each and every time in every laptop i need to manually enable the ActiveXObject from `(Tools / Internet Options / Security tab / Internet zone / Custom Level button / ActiveX controls and plug-ins section / Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting)`. Is there any way to enable it using via javascript?

I searched in internet and found that we can enable it via IObjectSafety Interface.Is that possible ? If yes how i can implement that ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Would you tell us which ActiveXObject do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object. ActiveXObject is only in IE11 for [legacy support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/activexobject-object-javascript).

> Creating an ActiveXObject on a remote server is not supported in
>   Internet Explorer 9 standards mode, Internet Explorer 10 standards
>   mode, Internet Explorer 11 standards mode, and Windows Store apps or
>   later.